# Display publish date on SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, modern-experience, sitepages, date

Is there a way to display the site page publish date on the page itself?

We would like to use this feature on the news post pages.

Comment: We can show the page publish date near page title, is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. That would be pefect.

Comment: Try below solution & let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This shows how to add the publish date on a page, but how do you show it on a site? The best would be to have it by default for all sites in that Hub if possible. Anyone that knows this? Like on this very site, if you look at the very button to the right.... Very greatful if you have an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Create a modern site page
2. Open it in **Edit** mode.
3. Click on Edit (Pencil icon) near page header/title

[image]

4. It will open property pane at the right side of page.
5. Change **Show published date** to **Yes**

[image]

6. Publish the page.
7. It will show the published date on page, like:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have a Wiki page in Sharepoint and I cannot find the icons you described above. Is there a way to add the publish date to a wiki page somehow? I found the page properties but it looks nothing like your screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: Steps given above in my answer are for modern "Site Pages". I think you are using classic experience pages.

Comment: How do I know if I am using Classic Experience? I cannot publish a screen shot in a comment.

Comment: check this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-classic-and-modern-experiences-5725c103-505d-4a6e-9350-300d3ec7d73f

Comment: Got it. The link says "There is no modern equivalent of a Wiki page." So I do not think it is possible to put the publish date automatically on a wiki page. I have done some searching and my search results also say this.

Comment: Yes, correct. You may need some custom solution for your requirements.